# Create two different kinds of users auth using firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to create with firebase two different auth for two different user's roles?

I'm building a website(using react and firebase) that is similar in its structure to Kahoot.
As in Kahoot, I'm trying to create users that can **create a quiz** and users that can **only play and answer** the quiz.
the users that create the quiz can log-in and answer a quiz, but the users which are signed as "players" cannot create a quiz and can only play.

I've created two different auth pages and I don't know how to handle this situation using firebase, does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During signup you can add add a variable in your Firebase Realtime Database for the user profile which identifies their role. Listen for the successful signup event and after that add the role value in database.

After singup / signin you will read that variable and do your navigation accordingly.

If the user **cannot** change their **role** between quiz creator and quiz player after signup, then you can add a security rule on the user role property to stop update of this value by the users.

Security rules of Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: thx. should I use the realtime database or the cloud firestore? does it matter? because I'm currently saving data about the users in the cloud firestore...

Comment: you can use firestore as well, the process will be same